# I only get the first user in the group to says its in the group

Tags: groups, user, csom

Hi i have created a group named 'MyGroup' in the group i have two user.
In my code i get the group that the user are in, 
But only with the first user in the group my alert are displayed that my first user is a member of the group, then when i log in with my second user, (he is a member of the group also) my alert does not display that he is a member of the group?

In my page layout i have this code

```
    <script>
    function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {


        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentWeb = context.get_web();

        var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);

        var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
        context.load(allGroups);

        var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
        context.load(group);

        var groupUsers = group.get_users();
        context.load(groupUsers);

        context.executeQueryAsync(
                function(sender, args) {
                   var userInGroup = IsUserInGroup(currentUser,group);         
                   OnComplete(userInGroup);
                },
                function OnFailure(sender, args) {
                   OnComplete(false);
                }
        );

        function IsUserInGroup(user,group)
        {
            var groupUsers = group.get_users();
            var userInGroup = false;
            var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
            while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();


                if (groupUser.get_id() == user.get_id()) {

                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;

                }
        else    
        {
        break;
        }
                }
                return userInGroup;
            }
    }

    function IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms()
{


    IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("MyGroup", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        alert(isCurrentUserInGroup);




     }

  });


    }

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms, 'SP.js');

</script>
```

Comment: In Group Permission, who all can view members of the Group?

Comment: @AmalHashim The problem is even if the user are in mycustom group i still says true that the user is a member of the group,

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have break in else?

```
else    
{
   break;
}
```

Just remove it as it is allowing you to loop through only once in any case.

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: When removing the break, i get true that user are in group even if he is not